# Django: how to update a user profile

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently creating a workout application/blog using Django. What I'd like to do is every time the user enters in a new blog post, the program should look at the exercise fields and update their user profile with the max values for various lifts (deadlift, bench press, etc).

I'm quite new to Django and it hasn't quite clicked on how models can interact with each other in this way

I have the Profile class in user\models, which is the area I want to update.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    max_squat = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    max_bench = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    max_deadlift = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    max_ohp = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
    squat_reps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bench_reps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    deadlift_reps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ohp_reps = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then I have the blog post class, which has the variables in which the user enters for each blog post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    workout = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=const.WORKOUTS, default='deadlift')
    weight = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sets = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    reps = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Tried something like this but no joy:

```
profile = Profile()
profile.max_deadlift = weight
profile.save()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: get the profile first by querying like this, `profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)`

Comment: What you need to do is link the `Post` model to the `Profile` directly with your ForeignKey. Once that's done, you can do `Post.objects.get` which will return a post object and then `post_object.profile.max_deadlift = some value`  and then `post_object.profile.save()`. Finally, you can also use signals which is probably a little more advanced.